# async call in Svelte derived store is run on every component

Tags: svelte

In a Svelte project, I have the following stores in a file:

```
export const selectedParams = writable({
  stations: [],
  variables: []
});

const getValuesData = async (selectedParams) => {
// make async call and return results for the stations and variables
}

export const stationsData = derived(selectedParams, ($selectedParams, set) => {
  getValuesData($selectedParams).then(set)
}, [])
```

I have two different components that can mount the derived store `stationsData`.  I would like that, if the `selectedParams` don't change, the derived store `stationsData` is not recalculated every time I mount a component that uses the store.

Is this possible or I have to create a writtable store and trigger the `getValuesData` function manually when changing the `selectedParams` and set the value to the results?

Answer (score 2):

[From the docs](https://svelte.dev/docs#derived): "The callback runs initially when the first subscriber subscribes and then whenever the store dependencies change." This means your `derived` store runs every time, and there's nothing to change that.

You could solve this either by using a `writable` store and trigger the computation every time `selectedParams` change, like you proposed. The drawback is that this also calculates data if it's not needed - not sure if that is even a problem in your case.

The other possible solution would be to enhance the code in the `derived` store to check if the params actually have changed before making the call.

```js
export const selectedParams = writable({
  stations: [],
  variables: []
});

const getValuesData = async (selectedParams) => {
// make async call and return results for the stations and variables
}

let lastSelected;
let lastStationsData = [];
export const stationsData = derived(selectedParams, ($selectedParams, set) => {
  // isDifferent depends on how you update the store,
  // could just be lastSelected !== $selectedParams if you create a new object
  // for each param change
  if (isDifferent(lastSelected, $selectedParams)) {
    getValuesData($selectedParams).then(res => {
      lastStationsData = res;
      lastSelected = $selectedParams;
      set(res);
    });
  }
}, lastStationsData);
```

You could extract that "only rerun when inputs changed" functionality into a generic custom store.

Comment: It's working fine, but I don't understand the sentence in the docs. If the callback runs when the first subscriber subscribes, then a second subscriber shouldn't run it. Maybe it's because the first subscriber is destroyed and a new one is created?

Comment: That is exactly why this is happening. You said you use it in two components between which you switch. The first one unmounts, which means the last subscriber unsubscribes from derived, which in turn means the next mount reruns the store.